# Howto handle forms in a Angular 4 + Redux setup

Tags: forms, angular, redux

I successfully implemented `@angular-redux/store` and `redux` in my minimal Angular 4 boilerplate.
I do understand the idea behind the Redux loop, but I have a hard time to get me past the simple counter increment button examples.

At the moment I have build a simple login form as a component that needs to grab a JWT token from my API.
I don't want to make it too complex, so for now I don't want to store the form state in the store, since a form component doesn't effect other components, right?

So when I hit the submit button, my `login.component.ts` will handle the validation and http request to my API.
But a form submit is also an action, so when does Redux comes in to play here?

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to use redux for a login form(this is not state related), use a reactive form instead so you can easily validate the input with built in functionality: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: It already is a reactive form. But logged in and logged out are states right?

Comment: I don't have much experience with redux, but seem this article might somehow answer your question.
http://brianflove.com/2017/04/10/angular-reactive-authentication/

Comment: @user3411864 unless you want the user to login every time he visits the application i would advice you to store the JWT in local storage. Then you can use a service to check if the user is still logged in. You could use this service to set the loggedIn state I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to keep form state in the store. Use a reactive form to handle validations and changes. You dont have to keep everything in the store.

When an action is needed you will dispatch it like this:

```
this.store.dispatch({ type: ACTION_TYPE, payload: this.form.value });
```

This action will trigger an **effect**, which will call the login API. After a success, or an error, you need to dispatch a new action to handle it.
If your call succeeds, you will dispatch an action from this effect for example `LOGIN_SUCCESS` which you will handle in another effect which will call for example the 'Get user data' API which you will save in the store. As for the `jwt`, in the effect you can save it in `localStorage` so the application remembers the logged in state. In your code you probably have an `AuthenticationService` that has an observable property `status`, which tells if the user is logged in.

If an error happens, you need to save this in some errors property in your store and display it on the form.

Comment: So dispatch is not the same as storing? Because you dispatch the full form payload to the store?

Comment: @user3411864 Dispatch only starts an action. You have to handle this action in an effect and eventually in a reducer. The reducer returns the new state, while an effect for an example calls an API. The action itself does nothing. The payload is arbitrary, you can pass whatever you need for the said action.

Comment: I'm having this image on my wall https://uploads.toptal.io/blog/image/121874/toptal-blog-image-1484754099125-659f9aa8dbf05fea9aa209dc1de0f5e2.png but probably it is not accurate anymore. Where does the effects fits into this schema? Are you referring to `@ngrx/effects` ? From a Udemy course I learned that I need to dispatch a LOGIN_BUSY action in the onSubmit() function in my component.ts file, do the async call to the API, and on success dispatch a second call LOGIN_SUCCEED. What is wrong with that approach?

Comment: @user3411864 There is nothing wrong. Yes, I'm referring to @ngrx/effects. It is only a layer in between reducers and actions that abstracts away some of the work for you. As I said, you can use them for API calls and to dispatch new actions. What you saw on the course would is the same, only you would do the async call in the effect and on success you would dispatch LOGIN_SUCCEED which you would then handle in your reducer.

Comment: So in the schema image, the effects library is basically the "DISPATCHER" block? It receives all the application actions. Pass the actions to the reducers that are not meant for effects or take an action that is meant to be handled as an effect and spit out one or more actions. Am I close ?

Comment: Almost there. Effects are more to the side. They are completely optional. They listen to actions and can dispatch new ones. Since they are optional they lie between the dispatcher and reducer. You can go directly action to reducer or action to effect to reducer. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: It now is :-) but why not making the reducers smarter? In other words why do reducers be pure functions?

Comment: @user3411864 The redux pattern is like this. You never mutate the state, you always return a new instance. I cannot list all the advantages(you can find it online easily), but the best thing is the unidirectional data flow and the fact that it pairs very nicely with Angular OnPush change detection because of this immutability.

Comment: A great sentence I found in the [Reactive Programming with Angular and ngrx book](http://www.apress.com/us/book/9781484226193 "title"): Once connected to the store’s stream, a **specific** action 
can be **interrupted** and **transform** the stream to a new action.

Answer (score 6):

Forms are essentials a means to collect user data and all the validations are like checks that you perform on that data to make sure it is usable for your application for future processing.

For such a scenario a reactive form is the best you can use, it will give you all the flexibility you need to add validators and logic to the form and maintaining everything in a single spot.

Only after all validations and checks are done when you hit the submit you can dispatch the whole form data as a payload into the state as object.

like this `this.store.dispatch({ type: Form_Data , payload : this.form.value});`

Which will then move around your application. for further processing. as a part of your state.

For more info on using reactive forms check this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/reactive).

More on ngrx [Link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/ngrx)

A whole app build on ngrx v4 working [example](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/FootBallScores) its repo [link](https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/FootBallScores)

Answer (score 6):

I know this is several months old now, but I respectfully disagree with both previous answers in that using the Reactive Forms methods for managing your forms creates a lot of challenges because then you're not using your store as the central and single location of truth -- you're mixing Redux philosophy with Angular philosophy for managing state and whenever you do that, it can get messy.

If you do not keep the form state in the store, then it is more challenging to bring that form state back if, for example, the user is in a flow and goes forward and comes back to the page they were just on.  With the form state saved, you simply read the form state to bring it back.  Otherwise, you have to come up with some other way to store the state, which will mean some janky passing around of data through parent and child components (assuming a Single Page Application style in the first place) -- which will also, notably, be separate from the redux store you're already managing.

If you're going redux, my battle-tested suggestion is to focus on making components dumb and having your store drive everything [as pure redux as possible]; meaning, all the components do is read from the store, assign local variables, and call services (some of which dispatch actions).  You can use Reactive Forms (e.g. FormBuilder and FormGroups), but have the form validation driven by redux and your store (e.g. you can implement @angular-redux/form and intercept the `@@angular-redux/form/FORM_CHANGED` call in your own reducer using the `action.payload.path` to distinguish which form is being called to perform validation, etc. -- this also stores to the store on every user action and doesn't mean you store nothing if a finish/submit button isn't pressed, which is what would happen in Rahul's case).

While the previously given answers can work, I don't think they provide the best developer or user experiences.  If you use redux, then stick with redux philosophy over Angular when managing state and user input whenever possible and you'll find the marriage between Angular and Redux to be a really fantastic union.

To respond directly to your specific question: "So when I hit the submit button, my login.component.ts will handle the validation and http request to my API. But a form submit is also an action, so when does Redux comes in to play here?"  The way I would construct this is to have your login component make a service call that then makes an http call that returns an observable and then handle the response with your store, like with a service call to dispatch an action with a payload (changing the state of the page or storing information that is returned).  Minimalist mock example below [Note: please remember your security practices of using https, clearing the store when appropriate, etc. if you're implementing a real login]:

login.component.ts:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  stylesUrls: ['./login.component.css']
}
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  username: string;
  password: string;
  login_failed: boolean;
  login_failed_message: string;
  @select(['main','login']) getLogin Observable<ILogin>;

  constructor(private loginService: LoginService, private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Watch Changes on state
    this.getLogin.subscribe(login => {
      // Read Login
      if (login) {
        this.username = login.username;
        this.password = login.password;
        this.login_failed = login.failed;
        this.login_failed_message = login.message;
      }
    }

    // Initialize Login Form
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      username: [this.username],
      password: [this.password],
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.loginService.submitLogin(this.login, this.password)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(res => {
      if (res.status === 'success') {
        this.loginService.loadHomePage();
      } else {
        this.loginService.setLoginFailed();
      }
    },
    error => {
       this.loginService.setLoginServerCommunicationFailed(error);
    });
  }
}
```

login.service.ts:

```js
export class LoginService {

  constructor(private ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>, private http: Http) {
  }

  submitLogin(login, password) {
    const jsonBody = {
      login: login,
      password: password,
    }
    return this.http.post(`/myApiAddress`, jsonBody);
  }

  loadHomePage() {
    this.ngRedux.dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN::HOME_PAGE'});
  }

  setLoginFailed() {
    this.ngRedux.dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN::LOGIN_FAILED'});
  }

  setLoginServerCommunicationFailed(message: string) {
    this.ngRedux.dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN::LOGIN_SERVER_UNREACHABLE', payload: message});
  }
}
```

login-form.reducer.ts:

```js
import * as _ from 'lodash';
export function loginFormReducer(state: ILoginState, action: any) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case '@@angular-redux/form/FORM_CHANGED':
      // only acts on login form actions sent from @angular-redux/form
      if (_.isEqual(action.payload.path, ['login']) {
         // Real-time login validation
      }
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

login.reducer.ts:

```js
export function loginReducer(state: ILoginState, action: any) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGIN::LOGIN_FAILED':
      return {
        ...state,
        login: {
          ...state!.login,
          failed: true,
          message: action.payload,
        }
      }
    case 'LOGIN::LOGIN_SERVER_UNREACHABLE':
      return {
        ...state,
        login: {
          ...state!.login,
          failed: true,
          message: 'Server Unreachable',
        }
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

navigation.reducer.ts:

```js
export function navigationReducer(state: IAppState, action: any) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGIN::HOME_PAGE':
      return {
        ...state,
        router: '/home',
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

login.interface.ts:

```js
export interface ILogin {
  username: string;
  password: string;
  failed: boolean;
  message: string;
}
```

store.ts

```js
// Other Reducers
import { routerReducer } from '@angular-redux/router';
import { navigationReducer } from '...';
import { mainReducer } from '...';
// Redux Imports
import { composeReducers, defaultFormReducer } from '@angular-redux/form';
import { combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { routerReducer } from '@angular-redux/router';
export const rootReducer = composeReducers(
  defaultFormReducer(),
  navigationReducer,
  combineReducers({
    router: routerReducer,
    main: mainReducer,
  })
);
```

main.reducer.ts

```js
import { loginReducer } from '...';
import { loginFormReducer } from '...';
export const mainReducer =
  combineReducers({
    login: composeReducers(
      loginReducer,
      loginFormReducer,
    )
  })
```